# How to secure ajax handlers?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, request, handler, ashx

I am using post like this in http://www.mywebsite.com/hello.aspx page:

```
$.post("handler.ashx", {}, function (x) { alert(x); });
```

How to check the address from which the handler is running?

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
{
    // check if request is from http://mywebsite/hello.aspx          

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("test");
}
```

or... how to disable request handler from different domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) to check if the call is comming from your site. One very simple working example:

```
if( !context.Request.UrlReferrer.Contains("site.com/")) ) 
{
   context.Response.End();
   return;
}
```

In some rare cases that users overwrite the Referrer, this fails.